# OpenAI Gymnasium vectorized approach works slower than non-vectorized

Tags: python, parallel-processing, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm getting started with [OpenAI Gymnasium](https://gymnasium.farama.org/). My task is to speed-up trajectory generation. So to create N trajectories, I want to use a single parallel multi-env instead of running the same env N times with resets. I found the [vector](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/vector/) module of Gym and tried to use it. But for me it doesn't speed up the generation, moreover it's sometimes slower. Here's sample code:

## Vectorized

```
n_envs = 100
vec_envs = gym.vector.make("CartPole-v0", render_mode="rgb_array", num_envs=n_envs)
vec_envs.reset()
n_actions = vec_envs.action_space[0].n

%%time
t_steps = 1000
for iter_idx in range(t_steps):
    actions_batch = np.random.randint(low=0, high=n_actions, size=(n_envs,))
    new_s, r, terminated, truncated, info = vec_envs.step(actions_batch)
```

Here **%%time** gives me:

> CPU times: total: 5.8 s Wall time: 6.84 s

## Non Vectorized

```
env = gym.make("CartPole-v0", render_mode="rgb_array")
env.reset()
n_actions = env.action_space.n

%%time
t_steps = 1000

def gen_single_session(env, t_steps):
    for iter_idx in range(t_steps):
        action = np.random.randint(low=0, high=n_actions)
        new_s, r, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
        if terminated or truncated:
            env.reset()

for session_idx in range(100):
    gen_single_session(env, t_steps)
    env.reset()
```

And here **%%time** gives me:

> CPU times: total: 1.33 s Wall time: 1.3 s

In these lines I'm simulating the [Vector behavior](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/vector/#gymnasium-vector-vectorenv) (if subenv terminates, it will be automatically reset):

```
if terminated or truncated:
    env.reset()
```

If I change the env to **LunarLander-v2** I get closer runtimes: 13s vs 15s respectively.

Am I doing something wrong? What's the best way to make it parallel?